# How do I add a class to the CDI context (using Weld) that isn't under my control?

Tags: java, cdi, weld

In Spring if I wanted to add a class to my bean context I just create a class with @Configuration and then I would add a method that produces the bean annotated with @Bean. The method's return value would be the same as the class I'm trying to produce.

How do I do the same thing in CDI using Weld? I have beans that I need to put into the CDI context, but I'm not sure how to make them available to CDI.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-2.2/en-US/html_single/#_producer_methods

Comment: You're not limited to methods - take a look at sections 3.3/3.4 http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#producer_method